# Need PHP regular expression

Tags: php

I have a string like 'Hello link to page 17 link to page 1 link to page 3 link to page 10 link to page 13 link to page 16 How are you?' I want to replace 'link to page 1', 'link to page 3' etc. with ' '  from this string using php regular expression . Plz help . Thanks ..

Comment: I laughed. Here's a nice -1 for you.

Comment: Please, don't use "Plz"

Comment: regex is `/ link to page \d /g` to remove all the single digit links

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Actually I don't have knowledge in php regular expression, I have a little bit knowledge in automata regular expression. Thanks... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$string="'Hello link to page 17 link to page 1 link to page 3 link to page 10 link to page 13 link to page 16 How are you?' I want to replace 'link to page 1', 'link to page 3'";

echo preg_replace("/link to page \d+/","",$string); //
```

Comment: this will replace 17(multi digit numbers) too

Comment: @Ankit : Yes, it is \d+

Comment: but as you can see OP doesn't want to replace multi digit numbers like 17

Comment: Yes, he wants to. He was just too lazy to write down everything, so he stated "I want to replace 'link to page 1', 'link to page 3' etc."
The 'etc.' refers to those multi-digit numbers.